# How do I return full documents containing a distinct value using Spring Framework Aggregation?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Say I have some documents like this:

```
{
   "name" : "Wendy",
   "phone" : "123",
   "GroupId" : 1
}, 
{
   "name" : "Tom",
   "phone" : "234",
   "GroupId" : 1
},
{
   "name" : "Sally",
   "phone" : "345",
   "GroupId" : 3
},
{
   "name" : "Bob",
   "phone" : "456",
   "GroupId" : 3
},
{
   "name" : "Cortana",
   "phone" : "567",
   "GroupId" : 7
}
```

I'd like to return a list of full-data documents that contains the first occurrence of each distinct `GroupId`. I'm thinking Aggregation is the best route for a task like this. Here is what I have so far:

```java
MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(new Criteria());
GroupOperation groupStage = Aggregation.group("GroupId").first("$$CURRENT").as("??");
// I know the above line is semi-nonsensical

Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(matchStage, groupStage);

// I only need help creating the aggregation object, beyond this is just a MongoOperations aggregate call
```

It should be noted that I don't necessarily need to use aggregation so if there is a way to achieve this using a simple "find" then I'm okay with that.
I'm a MongoDb noob, sorry if my "have tried" section is not very useful. However, this is what I would want back:

```
{
   "name" : "Wendy",
   "phone" : "123",
   "GroupId" : 1
}, 
{
   "name" : "Sally",
   "phone" : "345",
   "GroupId" : 3
},
{
   "name" : "Cortana",
   "phone" : "567",
   "GroupId" : 7
}
```

Comment: You would use $first I think.

Comment: your desired output has duplicates, so if you use `$group` it will give you distinct output.

Comment: I wonder, do you need to distinct by whole document like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/df8pyw2x2cD

Comment: I'd want something like this: https://mongoplayground.net/p/OMfJZqxv5F0
But with just the original documents returned and not have them be wrapped up in objects called "data"... Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `$first` helps to get the first occurrence of the data

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
    group("GroupId")
        .first("name").as("name")
        .first("GroupId").as("GroupId")
        .first("phone").as("pnone"),
    project().andExclude("_id")
).withOptions(AggregationOptions.builder().allowDiskUse(Boolean.TRUE).build());

return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, mongoTemplate.getCollectionName(YOUR_COLLECTION_NAME.class), Object.class).getMappedResults();
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YdAyoRZ5G4k)

Comment: Sorry varman, I totally asked the question wrong and was basically asking a completely different question than what I wanted to ask. I corrected it, though.